# DApp BPMN architecture design

Tags: solidity, dapps

I want to design my dApp on **Ethereum** but i want to explain the application logic (smart contracts) through **BPMN** to explicit my decentralized exchange.. Can someone help to design my decentralized exchange or just tell me where can i find ressources to do that..

Thx in advance